# Guardar el estado de una escena e unity, función checkpoint

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d, guardar

Estoy realizando mi primer proyecto en unity, se trata de un simple juego de recolectar objetos para superar el nivel. He añadido unos checkpoint en el mapa, y aqui comienza mi problema. La idea es que si el jugador muere reaparezca desde ese punto, lo que es la posición del jugador vale, he usado "sharepreferences" y todo bien, ahora no sabría hacer que tambien se guarden los objetos que ya haya recogido, osea que si llegado al punto ha cogido 3 pues que esos 3 ya no aparezcan logicamente. He investigado y probado pero no me queda del todo claro, agradecería si me pudieran echar una mano ya que realmente es lo que me faltaría por concluir en esta primera estapa.
Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 0):

La solución más sencilla para tu problema, sería crear una variable *lastCheckpoint*, de tipo Vector3 dentro de tu script de Jugador, la cual puedes utilizar para guardar la posición del último punto por el que has pasado. Si solo necesitas guardar esta información, puedes guardar y cargar dicha variable utilizando los **PlayerPrefs**, funcionalidad que Unity incorpora por defecto en sus proyectos.

Puedes obtener más información sobre cómo guardar y cargar información en el siguiente enlace: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Espero haberte ayudado :)